# CI Build not uploading artifacts

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I am new and is trying set up a CICD pipeline. The CI build stage is not uploading artifacts as shown. I have provide the current yml script below. what are the steps to correct errors in order to generate an artifacts for deployment.

Gitlab yaml script:

```
stages:
 - build
 - deploy

variables:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  AWS_REGION: $AWS_REGION
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: $S3_BUCKET_NAME

build:
  tags: [docker]
  stage: build
  image: node:latest
  script:
    - cd client
    - npm install
    - CI='' npm run build-prod
  artifacts:
    expose_as: 'Arti-Reports'
    paths:
      - build.
    expire_in: 24 hour
    when: on_success
```

the build job in CI pipeline shown as:

```
Uploading artifacts for successful job
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: build.: no matching files                 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up file based variables
```

Comment: Just to check, the correct path really is `build.` with a dot in the end?

Comment: To build on @JamesZ's comment, if the path really should be `build.`, the issue is usually that the file is in a directory you're not expecting. To find where it is, I add the following commands at the end of the `script` section and examine the output to see if I can find where the `build.` file is so that I can update the path in the `artifacts` clause: `pwd` to see where we are right now, `ls -la` to spit out files in `pwd`, including "dot" files, `find . build.` If these changes still don't locate the file, you can change the `find` command to search in `/` instead of `.` (current dir).

Comment: Adam Marshall , Thank you for your prompt response. I managed to find the folder as per your guide. and is able to run my pipeline deploying to S3. Thanks and appreciate you assistance.

Comment: James Z, Thank you for looking and clarifying into this. Appreciated.